# Monetization disabled in my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-monetization

I have created a new channel on YouTube called Rancho's YouTube Channel last week. I have uploaded 3 videos that after that my monetization is disabled. How to fix this?

I have attached the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First: You need an AdSense account linked on your YouTube account.
Second: You must have 4000 watch hours and more than 1000 subscribers to earn money from YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/account_monetization